# How to reset a child component after adding a new item to store using ngrx?

Tags: angular, components, rxjs, ngrx

I have an angular 2 child component whose purpose is to add a new object to the store.

Ideally, I would like to push down the reset of the component -- in case the new/add is rejected in the reducer. However, I can't figure out how to force a push down to the child component.

Perhaps this is supposed to be done in the child component and I'm going down the wrong path?

Currently, my child component does the rest. How to I ask the app component to force a reset down the component chain? I'm new to ngrx and ng2.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'url-new',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='name' #newurl placeholder="Add a url" />
      <button (click)="save(newurl)">Add</button>{{nextId}}
    </div>
  `
})
export class UrlNewComponent {
  @Input() nextId:number ;
  @Output() create = new EventEmitter();

  name:string = '';
  itemtype:string = "Url";

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>){
    console.log("UrlNewComponent constructor nextId = " + this.nextId);
  }

  save(newurl){


    let newUrl: Url = {id: this.nextId, name: newurl.value };
    console.log("newUrl = " + JSON.stringify(newUrl));

    this.store.dispatch({ type: ADD_URL, payload: newUrl});

    this.nextId ++;
    this.name = '';
  }
  ngOnInit() {
        console.log('UrlNewComponent ngOnInit nextId : ' + this.nextId);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's the child component and what do you mean by "reset"?

Comment: If the save function doesn't reset the nextId and name, these keep the old values. But the parent control passes in the nextId as that value is calculated and set into the store as part of the reducer. I thought the app-component (where the store is kept) would pass in new values to its children but I have console.log in constructor and ngOnInit and these don't change. How do I get the parent to send in a new value to nextId after the reducer is done and state is changed, instead of having the child component figure it out and kept a copy of nextId?